# i18next translation is 404 Not Found in Storybook with i18next-http-backend

Tags: javascript, i18next, react-i18next, i18next-http-backend

I tried integrating `i18next` to my Storybook with `i18next-http-backend` and it is trying to load the translations file from `http://localhost:6006/public/locales/en/translation.json` but gets a 404. I have my language files inside my `app/public` directory ( `app` is a sibling of `stories` and `.storybook` directories )

[image: file structure]

My storybook `i18next.js` looks like below,

```js
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';


const ns = ['translation'];
const supportedLangs = ['en', 'es'];

i18n.use(initReactI18next)
  .use(HttpApi)
  .init({
    //debug: true,
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    defaultNS: 'translation',
    ns,
    supportedLangs,
  });

supportedLangs.forEach((lang) => {
  ns.forEach((n) => {
    i18n.addResources(
      lang,
      n,
      require(`../app/public/locales/${lang}/${n}.json`)
    );
  });
});

export {i18n};
```

I tried adding `loadPath` configs also ( following [this][2] ) but still getting the issue.

```js
  .init({
    //debug: true,
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    ...
    backend: {
      loadPath: `/public/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json?lng={{lng}}&{{ns}}`,
      // loadPath: `/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json?lng={{lng}}&{{ns}}`, tried this too
    },
```

---

Following is how my `.storybook/preview.js` looks like

```js
import { muiTheme } from 'storybook-addon-material-ui';
import { theme } from '@internal/component-library';
import {i18n} from './i18next.js';

export const decorators = [
  muiTheme([theme])
];
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  i18n,
  locale: 'en',
  locales: {
    en: 'English',
    es: 'Spanish',
  },
}
```

My `package.js` has the following `scripts` for Storybook

```
"scripts": {
  ...  
  "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
  "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
}
```

Comment: So what is the exact url for the file not found in the browsers development tools?

Comment: `http://localhost:6006/public/locales/en/translation.json` is the exact URL it's trying to load. I'm not sure where this file is actually available. 

```
Request URL: http://localhost:6006/public/locales/en/translation.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```